# PHP Viewer for hlp files

Tags: php, viewer

I'm working on a project and i have all the help related to the business in hlp files, i'm looking for a php viewer for that kind of files but i have not found any so far, not even a payed one.

is there any library for displaying HLP files in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "display in php"? Would you like to be able to display .chm/.hlp (which are two different formats) on a web page?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i just want to know if there is any way to display hlp files in a webpage.

Comment: I found what i was looking for, its called [WinhelpCGI](http://www.herdsoft.com/linux/produkte/winhelpcgi.html), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find one for PHP, but there are various ones for Linux. You could convert it there, using `system()`, and then pick up the output.